# RegEx - 20 Characters long numbers only with spaces How

Tags: c#, regex

I'm completely useless at regex what I need to do is define a pattern that will allow a string that is a minimum of 5 characters a maximum of 20 characters will allow spaces and numbers only, no A-Z.

Any ideas?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z ]{5,20}$` should work.

Comment: `@^[\sa-zA-Z]{5,20}$`

Comment: By characters do you mean letters or do you need symbols, too?

Comment: These links might help you:
http://www.regexr.com/
http://txt2re.com/

Comment: only numbers and spaces

Comment: Then you need: `^[\d ]{5,20}$`

Comment: just edited the question thanks... if its ^[\d ]{5,20}$ post it as an answer if it works ill mark it as answered thanks guys @anubhava

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
@"^[\d ]{5,20}$"
```

Explanation:

```
^              # the beginning of the string
 [\d ]{5,20}   # any character of: digits (0-9), ' ' (between 5 and 20 times)
$              # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```